Web Application Firewall causing unexpected caching of Tomcat application
I have a tomcat web application that ia behind a Web Application Firewall (WAF). This web application occasionally gets updated and a new version gets deployed to the Tomcat server.
During the last deployment, I noticed a very strange issue where all the static files in the application (js, css etc) are from the old version of the application, but all the dynamic parts (jsp) are from the new deployment. Obviously, this causes a lot of problems.
I have tried several things:

Clearing the temp and work directories in Tomcat
Deploying from war file
Deploying by manually copying files
Deleting the application and redeploying
Restarting Tomcat
Restarting the entire server

Finally, I realized that the new deployment works perfectly when accessed from the server directly (without the WAF).
Is seems that the WAF is somehow caching the files. Can I somehow force the WAF to clear its cache? Is there an issue with the way I am deploying the application (Note: This is a Spring Boot application)
NOTE: I do not have direct access to the WAF, I just want to find out if there are any steps I can take before reaching out to the department that manages the WAF for my team.

Please check [help/on-topic] (as this question is not about a programming-related problem, thus off-topic on stackoverflow) as well as [ask] for when you ask the question somewhere where it's on-topic: You're asking how to configure your WAF, but other than the generic kind of system, we don't know anything about it.
